# how to add asp.net validations in visual studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net

I want to use validations in visual studio toolbox, but when I run my code I face with this error. how can I correct it?

"Web Forms Unobtrusive Validation Mode requires a Script Resource Mapping for 'j query'. Please add a Script Resource Mapping named j query(case-sensitive)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this

`<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />`

in your **web.config** file.